# Set up constructor for JavaScript object module pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is my first implementation of a JavaScript object using the Module Pattern. I need to add a constructor to the object, however, and for whatever reason every attempt I make hasn't worked, so I assume I'm setting the object up incorrectly and/or missing some syntax somewhere.

How would I add just a simple, parameter-less constructor to the object below?

```
var DisplaySettings = {
    //Default display settings for each producer type
    HandleAssignedView: function () {
        var producerType = $('#drpProducerType :selected').text();
        switch (producerType) {
            case "Agency":
                this.AgencyView();
                this.AgencyOptions();
                break;
            case "Sole Proprietor":
                this.NonProducerView();
                this.NonAgencyOptions();
                break;
            default:
                this.ProducerView();
                break;
        }
    },

    //Preserves database values on Edit page load
    LoadAssignedView: function () {
        var producerType = $('#drpProducerType :selected').text();
        switch (producerType) {
            case "Agency":
                this.AgencyView();
                break;
            case "Sole Proprietor":
                this.NonProducerView();
                break;
            default:
                this.ProducerView();
                break;
        }
    },

    AgencyView: function() {
        this.DisplayAgencyFields();
        this.AgencyLabels();
    },

    ProducerView: function () {
        this.DisplayProducerFields();
        this.NonAgencyLabels();
    },

    NonProducerView: function() {
        this.DisplayNonProducerFields();
        this.NonAgencyLabels();
    },

    DisplayAgencyFields: function() {
        $('.AgencyFields').show();
        $('.NonProducerFields').show();
        $('.NonAgencyFields').hide();
        $('.ProducerFields').hide();
    },

    DisplayProducerFields: function () {
        $('.AgencyFields').hide();
        $('.NonProducerFields').hide();
        $('.NonAgencyFields').hide();
        $('.ProducerFields').show();
    },

    DisplayNonProducerFields: function() {
        $('.AgencyFields').hide();
        $('.NonProducerFields').show();
        $('.NonAgencyFields').show();
        $('.ProducerFields').show();
    },

    NonAgencyLabels: function() {
        //Change DRM labels
        $('label[for=DRMCompanyName]').text('DRM Company Name');
        $('label[for=DRMCompanyId]').text('DRM Company Id');

        //Replace header text
        var newval = $('#HeaderText').text().replace("Agency", "Agent");
        $('#HeaderText').text(newval);

        //Adjust fieldset legend text
        $('#AgentTypeFields').children('legend:first').text('Producer Info');
    },

    AgencyLabels: function() {
        //Change DRM labels
        $('label[for=DRMCompanyName]').text('DRM Parent Name');
        $('label[for=DRMCompanyId]').text('DRM Parent Id');

        //Change h2 text to 'Agency' from 'Agent'
        var newval = $('#HeaderText').text().replace("Agent", "Agency");
        $('#HeaderText').text(newval);

        //Adjust fieldset legend text
        $('#AgentTypeFields').children('legend:first').text('Agency Info');
    },

    AgencyOptions: function() {
        $('#JIT').attr('checked', false);
    },

    NonAgencyOptions: function() {
        $('#WelcomeLetter').attr('checked', false);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this by moving all your methods to the prototype of the constructor:

```
function DisplaySettings() {
    // constructor initialization code here
}

DisplaySetttings.prototype = {
    //Default display settings for each producer type
    HandleAssignedView: function () {
        var producerType = $('#drpProducerType :selected').text();
        switch (producerType) {
            case "Agency":
                this.AgencyView();
                this.AgencyOptions();
                break;
            case "Sole Proprietor":
                this.NonProducerView();
                this.NonAgencyOptions();
                break;
            default:
                this.ProducerView();
                break;
        }
    },

    //Preserves database values on Edit page load
    LoadAssignedView: function () {
        var producerType = $('#drpProducerType :selected').text();
        switch (producerType) {
            case "Agency":
                this.AgencyView();
                break;
            case "Sole Proprietor":
                this.NonProducerView();
                break;
            default:
                this.ProducerView();
                break;
        }
    },

    AgencyView: function() {
        this.DisplayAgencyFields();
        this.AgencyLabels();
    },

    ProducerView: function () {
        this.DisplayProducerFields();
        this.NonAgencyLabels();
    },

    NonProducerView: function() {
        this.DisplayNonProducerFields();
        this.NonAgencyLabels();
    },

    DisplayAgencyFields: function() {
        $('.AgencyFields').show();
        $('.NonProducerFields').show();
        $('.NonAgencyFields').hide();
        $('.ProducerFields').hide();
    },

    DisplayProducerFields: function () {
        $('.AgencyFields').hide();
        $('.NonProducerFields').hide();
        $('.NonAgencyFields').hide();
        $('.ProducerFields').show();
    },

    DisplayNonProducerFields: function() {
        $('.AgencyFields').hide();
        $('.NonProducerFields').show();
        $('.NonAgencyFields').show();
        $('.ProducerFields').show();
    },

    NonAgencyLabels: function() {
        //Change DRM labels
        $('label[for=DRMCompanyName]').text('DRM Company Name');
        $('label[for=DRMCompanyId]').text('DRM Company Id');

        //Replace header text
        var newval = $('#HeaderText').text().replace("Agency", "Agent");
        $('#HeaderText').text(newval);

        //Adjust fieldset legend text
        $('#AgentTypeFields').children('legend:first').text('Producer Info');
    },

    AgencyLabels: function() {
        //Change DRM labels
        $('label[for=DRMCompanyName]').text('DRM Parent Name');
        $('label[for=DRMCompanyId]').text('DRM Parent Id');

        //Change h2 text to 'Agency' from 'Agent'
        var newval = $('#HeaderText').text().replace("Agent", "Agency");
        $('#HeaderText').text(newval);

        //Adjust fieldset legend text
        $('#AgentTypeFields').children('legend:first').text('Agency Info');
    },

    AgencyOptions: function() {
        $('#JIT').attr('checked', false);
    },

    NonAgencyOptions: function() {
        $('#WelcomeLetter').attr('checked', false);
    }
};
```

You would then create an object like this:

```
var settings = new DisplaySettings();
```

And call methods like this:

```
settings.LoadAssignedView();
```

---

FYI, the usual convention in Javascript is that constructors have initial caps like `DisplaySettings`, but methods do not have initial caps.

Comment: Thanks. One more question/things i think I'm missing. I need to attach the `HandleAssignedView` method to an event handler on a drop down. It can't seem to call any of the methods so long as I place the `()` syntax after the method name. Is this because those methods are out of scope when calling this as an event (i.e. I'm only attaching the `HandloeAssignedView` method, none of the ancillary methods), and if so is there a way around this that doesn't break best practices?

Comment: @NealR - To pass a function reference, you would use ONLY `settings.HandleAssignedView` without any parens after it.  Including the parens like `settings.HandleAssignedView()` calls it now.  Without the parens is a reference to the function so it can be called later.  Keep in mind that `this` inside an event handler will be what the event handler sets `this` to, not your object.

Comment: Ah, that's probably what it is. I'm calling `this` in the `handleAssignedView` to call the object methods. What would be the syntax for calling those methods in that context (event handling)? Simply replace `this.agencyView()` with `agencyView()`?

Comment: @NealR - It depends upon whether you need the `this` from the event handler.  If you just want to replace `this` with your object, you can use `.bind()` when passing the event handler.  Instead of passing `settings.handleAssignedView`, you would pass `settings.handleAssignedView.bind(settings)`.  Internally, this creates a stub function that will set up `this` for you before calling `handleAssignedView` and the stub function is the actual event handler.  You can read about `.bind()` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).